# Regular Expression to match break line

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to delete htmlA.
The border start from

**<{if $data.nowPage>1}>** to **/div> *1 breakLine* <{/if}>**

htmlA

```
<{if $data.nowPage>1}>
<div class="pageArrow pageFirst"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=1"><span class="icon arrow-first"></span></a></div>
<div class="pageArrow pagePrev"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=<{$data.nowPage-1}>"><span class="icon arrow-left"></span></a></div>
<{/if}>
```

I have tried

```
$fullHtml = readFileData($file);
preg_match("/(<{if \\\$data\.nowPage>1}>(.*?)<\/div>)(\s)(.+?)<{\/if}>/si",$fullHtml,$htmlA);
//$fullHtml = preg_replace(...,'',$fullHtml);
```

but it stopped too early and why print_r($htmlA) shows 5 keys?

```
Array
(
    [0] => <{if $data.nowPage>1}>
        <div class="pageArrow pageFirst"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=1"><span class="icon arrow-first"></span></a></div>
        <div class="pageArrow pagePrev"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}>
    [1] => <{if $data.nowPage>1}>
        <div class="pageArrow pageFirst"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=1"><span class="icon arrow-first"></span></a></div>
    [2] => 
        <div class="pageArrow pageFirst"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=1"><span class="icon arrow-first"></span></a>
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
        <div class="pageArrow pagePrev"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}>
)
```

fullHtml. line3 to line6.

```
<div class="pageContainer">
    <div class="pageBox">
        <{if $data.nowPage>1}>
        <div class="pageArrow pageFirst"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=1"><span class="icon arrow-first"></span></a></div>
        <div class="pageArrow pagePrev"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=<{$data.nowPage-1}>"><span class="icon arrow-left"></span></a></div>
        <{/if}>

        <{for $i=$data.nowPage-$data.pageFit to $data.totalPage}>

            <{if $data.nowPage == ($i)}>
                <div class="pageBtn active"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><{$i}></a></div>
            <{else if $i>($data.nowPage+$data.pageFit)}>
                <div class="pageMore"><span class="icon moreIcon"></span></div>
                <{break}>
            <{else if $i>0}>
                <{if $i==$data.nowPage-$data.pageFit && $i>1}>
                <div class="pageMore"><span class="icon moreIcon"></span></div>
            <{/if}>
                <div class="pageBtn"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=<{$i}>"><{$i}></a></div>
            <{else}>
            <{/if}>

        <{/for}>

        <{if $data.nowPage<$data.totalPage}>
        <div class="pageArrow pageNext"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=<{$data.nowPage+1}>"><span class="icon arrow-right"></span></a></div>
        <div class="pageArrow pageLast"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=<{$data.totalPage}>"><span class="icon arrow-last"></span></a></div>
        <{/if}>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to escape your parentheses when you intend to treat them as characters rather than as boundaries for a capture group.

Comment: note that this will only work if you can confirm there is no nested loop, which already breaks for the if's in your for loop.

Comment: @phatfingers I dont' understand. htmlA didn't have () on the boundaries.

Comment: Meh... I think I was missing my reading glasses.  Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a pattern for your task, given your sample input.

Pattern: `~<{if \$data\.nowPage>1}>(?:\s+<div.*?</div>)+\s+<{/if}>~`

[Pattern Demo including leading and trailing whitespace adjustment](https://regex101.com/r/nO9toR/1)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OM3HP))

```
echo preg_replace('~<{if \$data\.nowPage>1}>(?:\s+<div.*?</div>)+\s+<{/if}>~','',$html);
```

- match the leading `if` line
- match one or more `<div>` lines
- match the closing `if` line

Comment: Thanks for the demo.

Answer (score 1):

This is your RegEx but you forgot to add a pattern to it and for this reason it stops as soon as a match is found:

```
(<{if \\\$data\.nowPage>1}>(.*?)<\/div>)(\s)(.+?)<\/div>\s*<{\/if}>
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

- `\s` means any kind of whitespace

> why `print_r($htmlA)` shows 5 keys?

`preg_match` function returns first value in array as whole match and other indexes hold a value captured by a capturing group. You have 4 capturing groups in your regex so it adds 4 more values in returning array which means total 5 keys.

### Better approach

Regex:

```
~<{if \$data\.nowPage>1}>.*?</div>\s*<{/if}>~si
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZxoFr/1)

PHP Code:

```
preg_match('~<{if \$data\.nowPage>1}>.*?</div>\s*<{/if}>~si', $str, $htmlA);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail. But the pattern didn't fit space https://regex101.com/r/ln3YMf/1

Comment: Then replace `\R*` with `\s*` in regex. Check out https://regex101.com/r/CSyF4Q/1 @AllenBooTung

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this out.

```js
const string = `<{if $data.nowPage>1}>
<div class="pageArrow pageFirst"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=1"><span class="icon arrow-first"></span></a></div>
<div class="pageArrow pagePrev"><a href="?<{if !empty($data.years)}>y=<{$data.years}><{/if}><{if !empty($data.month)}>&m=<{$data.month}><{/if}>&p=<{$data.nowPage-1}>"><span class="icon arrow-left"></span></a></div>
<{/if}>`;

console.log(string.match(/^<{if \$data.nowPage>1}>\n<div.*\n*<div.*\n*<\/div>\n<{\/if}>/));
```

Comment: Sorry, did not realize you are looking for a php solution.  I am not a php programer. But the problem in your expression should be the same. Your text has multiple "{/if}". You have to use"</div><{/if}>" for your last indicator. :)

Comment: This pattern solved my problem. "/<{if \\\$data\.nowPage>1}>(.*?)\/div(.*?)\/div>(.*?)<{\/if}>/si"